# Redirect to page with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a basic website with pages and directories. Currently the main landing page is at https://www.example.com/index.php

I would like add a marketing landing page which is located at:
https://www.example.com/app/index.php

I would like for my visitors to land on the marketing page when they come to my site's domain. Naturally I thought of .htaccess redirect, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

// Redirect landing page
Redirect /app/index.php /index.php
```

Curently I'm getting  error:

> **Internal Server Error** 
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask. Please take the time to edit your question (there is a button for that...) and explain in a precise manner what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Just a note: With what is going down with SSL recently, I'd make sure that "if" you are `https` as your domain examples *suggest* you are .... Make sure that's reflected in the address in the `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# Redirect landing page
Redirect ^app/index\.php$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

Also note that .htaccess only supports comments beginning with `#`